# Outdoor Outlet switch for Heat Cable

Tags: electrical, roof, heat

I will be replacing my Heat Cable on my roof. Currently we have to plug it in manually when we want it to 'run'. This isn't a big deal but is annoying.

I'm not to interested in the sensors, i'd just like an easier way to control this plugin/unplug process. I was thinking of getting an Outdoor Outlet Switch with Remote and connect the Heat Cable to that. Will that work or am I asking for a fire?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the switch is rated for the load it should be fine. Most of the cable heaters I have wired run on 12 amps or approximately 1500 watts or less (120V) if yours is similar you should be fine with 15 amp rated remote switch.

Comment: Cool! I could get away with this then I think (the cable I believe is 1200watts): https://www.amazon.com/Woods-32555-Weatherproof-Wireless-Converter/dp/B001Q9EFUK/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1477677124&sr=8-1&keywords=outdoor+electrical+switch+remote

Comment: it is weather proof and 1625W restive loads so you should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

If you get a switch, get the six dollar version, not the 99 cent version.  The 99 cent jobs may be "rated 15A" but they don't really mean that.

Or you could get [this switch](http://www.supplyhouse.com/Honeywell-T410B1004-White-Electric-Heat-Thermostat-for-Electric-Baseboard-Heat-4099000-p).  It's made for 30A, it switches two wires.  One wire is switched "hard" on/off.  The other wire is switched by the thermostat.  You'd have to wire it to a receptacle.